# How to count the number of elements added to an array and find the average of numbers added in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

How can the number of elements in an array be counted?

So the array can hold 10 elements, but not all are filled. 
How do I count the number of elements that are entered?

Also, what is the correct way to find the average of an array? 
What I have now gives me this,

The number of valid grades entered is 10
[D@7ea987ac[D@7ea987acAverage: 0.0

```
//validate strings entered by user         
     if(convertedInput >= 0 && convertedInput <=100){
      ValidArray[validArraycount] = convertedInput;
      validArraycount ++; 
     }
  }      
  catch(NumberFormatException e){
  }

     //Prints number of valid values entered
       System.out.println("The number of valid grades entered is " + vArrayLen);



     //for printing array backwards
     for (int i = (arraycount-1); i>=0; i--){
        System.out.print(ValidArray);

     } 
     //calculates sum of all values in array of ValidArray (of grades)
     for(double d : ValidArray){
        sum += d;
     }

      //avergae of valid number array 
     double average = (sum/ValidArray.length);

     System.out.println("Average: " + average);
  } 
}
```

Thank You.

EDIT: 
The input is suppose to be up to 10 strings. Anything can be entered. Valid strings are double numbers between 0-10 that can be 0 and 10. All strings not valid are discarded. 
As of now this is what my code looks like:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Grades{
   public static void main(String args[]){

  int arraycount = 0;
  final int SIZE = 100;
  int validArrayCount = 0;
  final int ValidArraySize = 100;
  int valuesinValidArray = 0; 


  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  String initialInput = new String ("");

  String [] sArray = new String[SIZE];
  double [] ValidArray = new double[ValidArraySize];

  double sum = 0; 

  boolean exit = false;

  System.out.println("You may enter up to 100 grades."); 
  System.out.println("When you are done entering grades, press the enter/return key.");


  //Prints to user. Stops if nothing is entered.
  while((arraycount < SIZE)&&(exit == false)){ 
     System.out.println("Enter line " + (arraycount+1) + ": "); 
     initialInput = reader.nextLine();  


     if (initialInput.length()<1){ 
        exit = true; 
     }
     else{
        sArray[arraycount]=initialInput; 
        arraycount++;
     }
  }

     //convert string to double 
  try{
     double convertedInput = Double.parseDouble(initialInput);

     //validate strings entered by user         
     if(convertedInput >= 0 && convertedInput <=100){
        ValidArray[validArrayCount] = convertedInput;
        validArrayCount ++;
     }
  }
  catch(NumberFormatException e){
  }
     //Prints number of valid values entered
       System.out.println("The number of valid grades entered is " + vArrayLen);



     //for printing array backwards
     for (int i = (ValidArraySize-1); i>=0; i--){
        System.out.println(ValidArray[i] + "");
     } 

     //calculates sum of all values in array of ValidArray (of grades)
     for(double d : ValidArray){
        sum += d;
     }

      //avergae of valid number array 
     double average = (sum/validArrayCount);

     System.out.println("Average: " + average); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: "So the array can hold 10 elements, but not all are filled. How do I count the number of elements that are entered?"  Define a variable and keep track of the count yourself.  (Actually, it looks like you already have a variable that holds the count.  Use that.)  That's pretty much the only way, unless you use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Java arrays aren't dynamic; once you initialize them they have a fixed length. Can you use a Collection like `ArrayList`? Also, are you sure you've included all of your requirements (it appears you are doing a number of other things)?

Comment: A `double[]` will have each entry initialized to zero by default.

Comment: I cannot use ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing it, also `ValidArray` is a terrible name. You forgot to use the array index in your `for` loop and the number you are using for that is `validArraycount` -

```
// Prints number of valid values entered
System.out.println("The number of valid grades entered is "
        + validArraycount);

// for printing array backwards
for (int i = validArraycount-1; i>=0; i--){
    System.out.print(ValidArray[i] + " "); // <-- don't forget the index.
} 
System.out.println(); // <-- next line.
double sum = 0;
// sum the values in array of ValidArray (of grades)
for(double d : ValidArray){
    sum += d;
}
// Average. Sum / the count 
double average = (sum / validArraycount);
System.out.println("Average: " + average);
```

Comment: Won't the index will print only that number. I don't want to do that. I want to print the entire array, just in the reverse order entered.

Comment: @KaraWilliam It's a loop. It will print each number from the end and a space. There should have a been `println()` after the loop (I'll edit it). Finally, I suggest you try it.

Comment: @KaraWilliam Then your array is empty.

Comment: But it shouldn't be because I inputed valid strings.

Comment: You can also use `Arrays.toString(ValidArray)` to get the array contents as a `String` from left to right; but if the above doesn't print right to left then the array is empty. Are you certain that `convertedInput` meets your test criteria?

Comment: This is for a beginners Java class. I haven't learned Arrays.toString(ValidArray).

Comment: @KaraWilliam Use it to look at your array contents; is there anything in your array? You haven't really posted much about you're populating the array. Good luck.

Comment: I posted an answer to my original question that explains more about what is in the array and what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

`validArrayCount` already holds the number of elements that are entered.

Instead of printing `vArrayLen` for the number of valid grades entered, print out `validArrayCount`:

```
System.out.println("The number of valid grades entered is " + validArrayCount);
```

To get the average, you can divide by `validArrayCount` instead of `ValidArray.length`:

```
double average = (sum/validArrayCount);
```

Also, you have to add the array indices when printing the array backwards:

```
// for printing array backwards
for (int i = validArrayCount-1; i>=0; i--){
    System.out.print(ValidArray[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println(); //For inserting a new line after printing all array elements
```